# How can i convert Details form into a json in powerapps?

Tags: json, sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

```
'PowerApp->Content'.Run(JSON(DetailForm1,JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData)
```

I am trying to put this action on a button but im getting an error

> the json function cannot serialise objects of type control

Is there any workaround to this? I want to send data to create a new excel file.

Comment: you will have to define your json, what is the attribute name (data structure) and it's value. you have nothing like this out of the box.

Comment: @AnkUser so the data structure is the form itself which includes data cards (with key value pairs) . I have around 8 datacards in the form

Comment: yes either create a collection with attribute name and value or create a json and add each attribute and it's value per hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to serialize the form itself, but the *updates* that the form would send to the data source associated with it. If that's the case, then you can use this expression:

```
'PowerApp->Content'.Run(JSON(DetailForm1.Updates))
```

Notice that the *edit form* control has an Updates property, while the *display form* control does not. Not sure which type your 'DetailForm1' is, but if it is a display form, you can replace it with an edit form, and set its DefaultMode property to FormMode.View, and that will make it essentially a display form.

Comment: Hi @carlosfigueira !! i see your point, i do have a separate screen for edits so this only displays the details hence there is no Updates attribute